# HiddenField Value changes via client

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using HiddenField in my Asp.net Page and store some value in it.
but user can changes it's value via firefox Firebug in client side and enter an invalid value in it.
so when user presses the submit button in the web page,invalid data will recieve in server side and invalid data will store in my database.
what can I do?

Comment: Don't give the user any more information than absolutely necessary. Hidden fields are great for helping the user experience, but the server needs to validate all input no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate the input on the server side. You should ALWAYS be doing that anyway, never trust users.

So basically whatever method you have in your code behind that handles saving data to the db needs to check all the data its sending first.

Comment: what about overload, if I want to check data entered with my database entries? what else can I use instead of hidden field which user can't change it's value? It's better to say I need to change the value via javascript.

Comment: It really depends on what your doing, and what your using the hidden field for. What type of info are you storing in the hidden field?

Comment: I have a textbox that user can search via it for skills and then the result shown in a grid view and he/she can select multiple skills from gridview. so for preventing postback I used jquery and ajax. so I need to store the equivalent values of every skill which selected by user in hiddenField and then pass it to server.

Answer (score 1):

Although, nothing can prevent client side hacking, you can make it harder for them to access the data.
Store the value in a JavaScript var then write the value to a hidden field onSubmit
Even with this method a good developers kit will allow you to change that also, but it is now as obvious as a hidden field.

Another thing about security is add more layers.

> - Use encrpytion
> - Store the data in your database
> - Don't store the values on the client side at all